# Using python3 locally while running pyspark3 jupyter kernel

Tags: python, pyspark, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Does anyone know how to change the specific instance of python invoked in the `%%local` spark magic when running a pyspark3 kernel in jupyter?

When running the PySpark3 kernel that ships with sparkmagic, I often want to pull data down to my local machine and do some calculations there.

However, the %%local magic only seems to be able to use the root system python, not python3 or a virtual env.

Here is my kernel.json:

```
{
"argv":["python","-m","sparkmagic.kernels.pyspark3kernel.pyspark3kernel", 
"-f", "{connection_file}"],
"display_name":"PySpark3"
}
```

I have `export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3` in my profile already.
I have also already tried tweaking the `kernel.json` by replacing the python argument with `python3`, `/usr/bin/python3`, and the path to a virtual environment